# How can I auto-format code on save in React project with Prettier and Tailwind CSS sorting?

Tags: tailwind-css, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

I am new to react and I don't use prettier generally. I am trying to use the prettier on my react project along with the tailwindcss class sorting. I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I have checked out the **format on save** in VS Code. I have set the **default formatter : Prettier ESlint**.

This is inside my .prettierrc.json file :

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
  }
```

This is my setting.json file :

```
{
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": false
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "plaintext": true,
        "markdown": true,
        "scminput": false
    },
    "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Sublime Material Theme - Dark",
    "update.mode": "manual",
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact",
        "*.css": "css"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "html.format.contentUnformatted": "",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint",
   
}
```

This is my package.json file :

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "eslint": "^8.38.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwind": "^2.2.12",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "vite": "^4.3.2"
    }
}
```

Prettier Version : v9.12.0
Prettier ESlint Version : v5.1.0
Vs Code version : v1.77.2

I ran command in the git bash terminal :
`npx prettier --check ./src/App.jsx`
and I got this error :
***[error] require() of ES Module C:\Users\bisha\Code\React\my-project\tailwind.config.js from C:\Users\bisha\Code\React\my-project\node_modules\tailwind-classes-sorter\lib\index.js not supported.
[error] Instead change the require of tailwind.config.js in C:\Users\bisha\Code\React\my-project\node_modules\tailwind-classes-sorter\lib\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.***

I copy pasted the error code in the chatGPT and it told me to do this :

```
// Before
const tailwindConfig = require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'tailwind.config.js'));

// After
const tailwindConfig = await import(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'tailwind.config.js'));
```

I couldn't find the line : *const tailwindConfig = require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'tailwind.config.js'));* in ***C:\Users\bisha\Code\React\my-project\node_modules\tailwind-classes-sorter\lib\index.js***

Nothing is working. I restarted the vs code too.

**My ultimate goal** is: My code in all file like jsx , html, css , json should be auto formatted on save. PLus  the tailwindcss classes should be sorted automatically too.
Please help.